# Array item gets the value "undefined"

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, set

I am trying to create an array of unique numbers from 0 to 10:

```
var numbers=[];
var i=0;
var prevLength=numbers.length;

while(numbers.length<10){
    prevLength=numbers.length;
    if(numbers.length<=prevLength){
        numbers[i]=Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
        numbers=[...new Set(numbers)];
        console.log(numbers);
        i++;
    }
}
```

But the output of the array will always have an undefined item at a random index which I don't know why.

```
[ 9, 1, 8, 7, undefined, 5, 2, 0, 6, 3 ]
```

Can somebody help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `new Set` removes a duplicate, then `i` will be larger than the length of numbers, due to `numbers.length` shrinking but `i` still getting increased. Don't keep track of an index, just use `.push` to push to the end of the array:

```js
var numbers=[];
var prevLength=numbers.length;

while(numbers.length<10){
    numbers.push(Math.floor(Math.random()*10));
    numbers=[...new Set(numbers)];
    console.log(numbers);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because of this statement:

```
numbers=[...new Set(numbers)];
```

This can potentially reduce the length of `numbers`, but as you don't align the value of `i` with the potential shortening, you'll get gaps.

The solution is to drop the use of `numbers[i] =` and use `numbers.push` instead:

```
numbers.push(Math.floor(Math.random()*10));
```

Answer (score 1):

A more efficient way to make use of the Set would be something like:

```js
const set = new Set()

while(set.size < 10){
   const rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
   !set.has(rand) && set.add(rand); 
}

const res = [...set]

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this without `Set`

eg:

```js
var numbers = [];
var rand;

while(numbers.length < 10){
    rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
    numbers.indexOf(rand) === -1 && numbers[numbers.length] = rand;
}

console.log(numbers);
```